# Division in batches of a 3D tensor (Pytorch)

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a 3D tensor of size say 100x5x2 and mean of the tensor across axis=1 which gives shape 100x2.
100 here is the batch size. Normally without batch, the division of tensor of shape 5x2 and 2 works perfectly but in the case of the 3D tensor with batch, I’m receiving error.

```
a = torch.rand(5,2)
b = torch.rand(2)
z=a/b
```

gives me expected answer.

```
a = torch.rand(100,5,2)
b = torch.rand(100,2)
z=a/b
```

Gives me the following error.

The size of tensor a (5) must match the size of tensor b (100) at non-singleton dimension 1.

How to divide these tensors such that my output is of shape 100x5x2 ? Something like bmm for division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
z = a / b.unsqueeze(1)
```

This adds an extra dimension in `b` and makes it of shape *(100, 1, 2)* which is compatible for broadcasting with `a`.